# Vectorized log1p() in RcppArmadillo

Tags: c++, rcpp, armadillo

What is the appropriate way to apply `log1p()` to an entire `arma::vec`? It seems that there are vectorized versions of `log()` and `exp()`, but not `log1p()`. I found that there's syntactic sugar for `NumericVector`, so I end up converting `arma::vec` to `NumericVector`, applying `log1p()`, then converting back:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec test_log1p( arma::vec v )
{
  // arma::vec res = log1p(v);         // results in a compilation error
  NumericVector v1 = log1p( wrap(v) );
  arma::vec res = as<arma::vec>(v1);
  return res;
}
```

Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [.transform()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#transform) or [.for_each()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#for_each) facilities available for Armadillo vectors and matrices. Example:

```
v.transform( [](double val) { return log1p(val); } );
```

or

```
v.for_each( [](double& val) { val = log1p(val); } );  // note the & character
```

You may need to use the `std` prefix: [`std::log1p()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log1p) instead of `log1p()`.

Comment: `.for_each()` was going to be my suggestion (+1). Note that OP will not need to use `std::log1p()`, since [RcppArmadillo pulls in Rcpp](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/blob/master/inst/include/RcppArmadillo.h), and [Rcpp ensures `log1p()` is defined](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/master/inst/include/Rcpp/Rmath.h) (see lines 227-28).

Comment: That's pretty much what I had in mind with the comment 'add a one-liner'.  We can _almost always_ add something like this whether Sugar has something premade or not.

Answer (score 5):

The devil is, once again, in the detail.

For starters, RcppArmadillo does not have 'Sugar' so your reasoning is flawed--you can't just look at the Rcpp Sugar functions that are working on `Rcpp::NumericVector`.

Then again, one can convert as you did. But you chose *an expensive* conversion.  Look into the advanced constructors explicitly reusing memory -- no copies needed.

A much simpler and more direct (yet local) approach would just be to add a little local inlined function. That's what I would do :)  Done in a few minutes.

Lastly, we have some sibbling projects that generalized Rcpp Sugar over anything that can take iterators. That is "the high road" and it could do with some fresh development. Maybe start [at this repo](https://github.com/dcdillon/RcppHoney).

Comment: Thanks, Dirk. I appreciate your insight.